# Testing interaction with external systems

Tags: unit-testing, bash, integration-testing

I have some bash scripts that interact with external systems such as SQL and SVN that I'd like to be able to write better unit tests for. For example, various types of database backups and restores against large production databases.

I guess some people might say this is integration testing rather than unit testing (where arguably you shouldn't depend on externals, touch the filesystem etc.). Creating the equivalent of a mock object doesn't really test much in this case - I want to make sure that the dump and restore can actually work. How would you do this, and how far would you go?

- Dump only the schema, restore locally and then insert test data in setup?
- Would you go so far as to test the archive function by comparing file sizes, check for gzip file type etc.?
- How would you test timing issues for such long-running tasks? Perhaps keep a complete snapshot to work on locally for testing?
- Would you also create local test repositories for SVN and other such dependencies?

Maybe I am thinking about this in completely the wrong way - quite new to formal testing. If so, what approach would you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot create a test version of your running system, then you need to create a test version of your database and repository.

On our test systems, our normal database processing scripts begin with something like this:

```
case `hostname` in
 *-test) dbname=db1-test ;;
 *)      dbname=db1 ;;
esac
```

This allows our normal, production SQL scripts to reference the correct database whether running on a production system or a test system (one ending with -test).

The important thing is to make your normal production scripts automatically adjust to the test environment.

If you don't have a separate test system, or a convention that allows a simple dbname choice, then perhaps using an environment variable to name the appropriate database name or respository?  RAILs does this with the RAILS_ENVIRONMENT variable.